# EPPlus - ExcelNamedRange - Is there a function like RefersTo

Tags: c#, epplus

In the original Excel Objects I have the property RefersTo like:

```
workbook.Names("TestRange").RefersTo
```

Is there an equivalent in EPPlus?

**UPDATE**

Here is a screenshot of the Excel Dialog and the field I want to write to. To open this Dialog in Excel goto: Formulars - Names-Manager

[image: here is a screenshot of the Excel Dialog and the field I want to write to]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that you are searching for?

```
sheet.Names["RangeName"].Start.Column
sheet.Names["RangeName"].End.Column
sheet.Names["RangeName"].Start.Row
sheet.Names["RangeName"].End.Row
```

**EDIT**

RefetsTo is the range/address of a named range.

To add a named range :

```
ExcelRange range = ws.Cells["A1:E5"];  // this is the RefersTo
ws.Names.Add("test", range);
```

To edit a named range :

```
ExcelRange newrange = ws.Cells["A1:F6"];  // this is the RefersTo
ws.Names["test"].Address = newrange.Address;
```

**EDIT**

To add a named range, that use a formula :

```
ws.Names.AddFormula("test2", "MAX(8,10,6,4,2)");
```

Comment: No. (Sorry for the late response...) If you open the NamesManager in Excel and edit a name there is a field called "refers to" ("bezieht sich auf" in german excel) at the bottom of the dialog. There I can enter a range but also special formulars, even some wich are not supported in normal excel cells like evaluate(). I would like to write to this field from EPPlus...

Comment: Sorry, but this is also not working. Address can only take valid Excel Range strings but not a Formula... refersTo can also take formulas.

Comment: Ah!  Got It!  `ws.Names.AddFormula("test2", "MAX(8,10,6,4,2)");`  Just type your formula, without first `=`

Comment: Is `.AddFormula()` is what you was searching for?

Comment: Yes and Yea!!!    Thanks!!!!   Can you edit your answer, than I accept it!  Just as an info: If I add a Formula in Names I have to save the File as xlsm and call CreateVBAProject on the Workbook. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250111/use-epplus-to-create-xlsm-file - otherwise Excel will not open the file.

Comment: The above adds a range scoped to the Worksheet.  If you want a workbook scoped range (accessible from all sheets) use something like this:
`ws.Workbook.Names.Add(ws.Cells["A1:E5"]);`